# How to display the label of a selected value of a <h:selectOneMenu> in a <h:outputText>?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I want to show the label of the selected value of `<h:selectOneMenu />` in a `<h:outputText />`.

I have the following dropdown where I get the selected value.

```
<h:column>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedCity}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="NewYork"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Washington"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:column>
```

I want to display the selected value, but the following only shows `1` or `2`.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.selectedCity}" />
```

I want to display the label `NewYork` or `Washington`. How can I do this?

Comment: I really don't get you. Post a mockup or some plain HTML code of how the result should look like.

Comment: Please provide the detailed question.

Comment: I only want to see the value of a <h:selectOneMenu>. I'd like the <h:selectOneMenu> shows like a <h: outputText>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update #2** based on the new edits and comments: ah we *finally* get somewhere (I removed the entire old answer, check edit history if you want to see it anyway).

You just need to maintain something like a `Map<Long, String> cities` somewhere in your model and then use it as follows:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.cities[bean.selectedCity]}" />
```

This will basically display `bean.getCities().get(bean.getSelectedCity());`. You could even reuse the map for `<f:selectItems>` so that you don't need to maintain it in two places.

Comment: If use `<h:outputText value="NewYork" />`, that's really not convenient. I get the value '1' from database, but I want to show it as 'NewYork'. I think `<h:selectOneMenu>` must be the best choice.

Comment: When I use rendered='false', I can't see the value of `<h:outputText>`, there is nothing.

Comment: Truly, that's also exactly what `rendered="false"` does :) When using `rendered="true"` it'll be displayed. But forget it, your concrete problem is now *finally* clear. See the answer update.

Comment: Really thank you BalusC. This is a good solution. Now I will try it :)

Comment: OK, was so kind to edit your question as well to reflect the concrete problem better.

Comment: I think I get another problem. The parameter 'bean.selectedCity' is not from java code, but is the value of the attribute 'var' of a `<h:dataTable>`.

Comment: Then just use that instead `#{bean.cities[item.selectedCity]}` (where `item` is the `var`). It was just a kickoff example.

Comment: Good morning BalusC.(Morning in China) I din't solve it. I should read some JSF book, then consult you. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see its value, you need to **use disable property** and displayClass

you can use the **t:selectOneMenu** tag with **diplayValueOnly="true"** property

```
<h:selectOneMenu  disable="true">
        <f:selectItem id="si1" itemLabel="Thums Up" itemValue="11" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" prefix="t"%>

 <t:selectOneMenu  displayValueOnly="true">
            <f:selectItem id="si1" itemLabel="Thums Up" itemValue="11" />
</t:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: There is a attribute called 'disabled' :) But it always show as a `<h:selectOneMenu>`. Maybe the displayValueOnly attribute is useful, but I use primefaces, not Myfaces.

Comment: In primefaces, I think there is no attribute as useful as `displayValueOnly` in myfaces.